# Powershell Listview.column.Imageindex delete image

Tags: winforms, powershell

I've created a Powershell Function that allows me to sort a listview by clicking on the column.

Depending on whether it is sorted in ascending or descending order, an image appears in the column with an arrow pointing up or down. If the column is changed, the arrow should be deleted again. That's why I set the value to -1. However, the image remains there. Maybe someone has an idea why the image is not deleted.

greetings

Jannik

```
function SortListView
 {
  param([parameter(Position=0)][UInt32]$Column)
  $Numeric = $true
  [Int]$Script:ColumnIndex = 0
   if($Script:LastColumnClicked -eq $Column)
   {
       If ($script:Image -eq 1){$script:Image = 0}Else{$script:Image = 1}
       $Script:LastColumnAscending = -not $Script:LastColumnAscending
       [Int]$Script:ColumnIndex = $Column
       $list_view.Columns[$Script:ColumnIndex].ImageIndex = $script:Image
   }
   else
   {
       $script:Image = -1
       $list_view.Columns[$Script:ColumnIndex].ImageIndex = $script:Image
       [Int]$Script:ColumnIndex = $Column
       $script:Image = 1
       $list_view.Columns[$Script:ColumnIndex].ImageIndex = $script:Image
       $Script:LastColumnAscending = $true
   }
```

Comment: You are missing important part of what you are trying to refresh.  In my eyes you have to reload the form, but that part is unknown or missing from your script

Comment: Why not using `DataGridView`?

Comment: This is not the mistake i can change the Image with the same principle without reload the form.

Comment: When i convert the ps1 file in an exe it works but not as ps1.